# The speed of training is reduced using a custom method in tensorflow.keras.layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I'm using `tensorflow.data` and `custom layers` to solve the bottleneck of data augmentation, but I found that using `tensorflow.data` alone is faster than mixing, I don't know what's going on in the `custom layers`, can someone please tell me?

Thanks in advance!

This is my data augmentation code, mainly to do standardization and resize.

```
def random_normalization(data, mean, std):
    mean = tf.multiply(mean, tf.random.uniform(shape=(), minval=0.5,maxval=0.9, dtype=tf.float64))
    std = tf.multiply(std, tf.random.uniform(shape=(), minval=0.5,maxval=0.9, dtype=tf.float64))
    return tf.divide((tf.subtract(data, mean)), std)

def random_resize(data):
    def resizing(index, data, choice, enable, new_data, number, overlap):        
        FrontEnd = tf.cond(tf.math.greater_equal(tf.subtract(index, overlap), tf.constant(0)),
                           lambda: tf.subtract(index, overlap),
                           lambda: index)
        
        BackEnd = tf.cond(tf.math.less(tf.add(tf.add(index, 10),overlap),tf.constant(2000)),
                          lambda: tf.add(tf.add(index, 10),overlap),
                          lambda: index)
        
        z1 = tf.gather(data, indices=[0], axis=1)
        z1 = tf.gather(z1, indices=tf.range(FrontEnd, BackEnd), axis=0)
        
        z2 = tf.gather(data, indices=[1], axis=1)
        z2 = tf.gather(z2, indices=tf.range(FrontEnd, BackEnd), axis=0)
        
        z3 = tf.gather(data, indices=[2], axis=1)
        z3 = tf.gather(z3, indices=tf.range(FrontEnd, BackEnd), axis=0)
        
        z4 = tf.gather(data, indices=[3], axis=1)
        z4 = tf.gather(z4, indices=tf.range(FrontEnd, BackEnd), axis=0)
        
        z5 = tf.gather(data, indices=[4], axis=1)
        z5 = tf.gather(z5, indices=tf.range(FrontEnd, BackEnd), axis=0)
        
        z6 = tf.gather(data, indices=[5], axis=1)
        z6 = tf.gather(z6, indices=tf.range(FrontEnd, BackEnd), axis=0)
        
        
        new_data = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(new_data, [[number, 0], [number, 1], [number, 2],
                                                          [number, 3], [number, 4], [number, 5]], 
                                               [tf.math.reduce_mean(z1), tf.math.reduce_mean(z2),
                                                tf.math.reduce_mean(z3), tf.math.reduce_mean(z4),
                                                tf.math.reduce_mean(z5), tf.math.reduce_mean(z6)])
        
        
        return tf.add(index, 10), data, choice, enable, new_data, tf.add(number, 1), overlap
    
    choice = tf.random.uniform(shape=(), minval=0,maxval=4,dtype=tf.int32)
    enable = tf.random.uniform(shape=(), minval=0,maxval=1,dtype=tf.float64)
    overlap = tf.random.uniform(shape=(), minval=5,maxval=21,dtype=tf.int32)
    
    new_data = tf.zeros((200,6), dtype=tf.float64)
    index = tf.constant(0)
    number = tf.constant(0)
    condition = lambda index, data, choice, enable, new_data, number, overlap: tf.less(index, 2000)
    r = tf.while_loop(condition, resizing, loop_vars=(index, data, choice, enable, new_data, number, overlap))
    return r[4]

def normal_resize(data):
    data = tf.reshape(data, (2000,6,1))
    data = tf.image.resize(data, size=[200,6])
    return tf.cast(tf.reshape(data, (200,6)),dtype=tf.float64)

def augmentation(data, labels):
    mean = tf.math.reduce_mean(data,axis=0)
    std = tf.math.reduce_std(data,axis=0)
    data = tf.cond(tf.random.uniform(shape=(), minval=0, maxval=1,dtype=tf.float64) < tf.constant(0.8,dtype=tf.float64), 
                   lambda: random_normalization(data, mean, std), 
                   lambda: tf.divide((tf.subtract(data, mean)), std))
    
    # 2000 resize to 200
    data = tf.cond(tf.random.uniform(shape=(), minval=0, maxval=1,dtype=tf.float64) < tf.constant(0.8,dtype=tf.float64), 
                   lambda: random_resize(data), 
                   lambda: normal_resize(data))

    return data, labels
```

Main code, including `tf.data` and model

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    trainDS = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((np.random.rand(3000,2000,6),
                                                  np.concatenate((np.zeros((1500)),np.ones((1500))))))
    trainDS = (
        trainDS
        .cache()
        .shuffle(1000, reshuffle_each_iteration=False)
        .map(augmentation, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
        .batch(128, drop_remainder=True)
        .prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE))
    
    input = Input((200,6))
    x = LSTM(64, return_sequences=True)(input)
    output = Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')(x)
    model = Model(input, output)
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='BinaryCrossentropy')
    model.fit(trainDS, epochs=3)
```

Then this is the code of my custom layer, although it is a bit cumbersome, it still achieves the result I want.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, Input
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Layer
import numpy as np

class CustomLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
    
    def execute(self, data, batch_size, new_data, _type):
        def _fun(index, data, _type, new_data):
            resized = tf.cond(_type,
                              lambda:augmentation(tf.reshape(tf.gather(data,[index]), (2000,6))),
                              lambda:normal_resize(tf.reshape(tf.gather(data,[index]), (2000,6))))
            values = tf.reshape(resized, (1,-1))[0]
            _Indices = self.createIndices(index)
            new_data = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(new_data, _Indices, values)
            return tf.add(index,1), data, _type, new_data
        
        index = tf.constant(0)
        condition = lambda index, data, _type, new_data: tf.less(index, batch_size)
        r = tf.while_loop(condition, _fun, loop_vars=(index, data, _type, new_data))
        return r[-1]
    
    def createIndices(self, BatchSizeIndex):
        def loop1(_i, BatchSizeIndex, col_num, _Indices):
            def loop2(_i, _j, BatchSizeIndex, col_num, _Indices):
                _Indices = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(_Indices, [[col_num, 0], [col_num, 1], [col_num, 2]], 
                                                        [BatchSizeIndex, _i, _j])
                return _i, tf.add(_j,1), BatchSizeIndex, tf.add(col_num,1), _Indices
            
            _j = tf.constant(0)
            condition_loop2 = lambda _i, _j, BatchSizeIndex, col_num, _Indices: tf.less(_j, 6)
            r_loop2 = tf.while_loop(condition_loop2, loop2, loop_vars=(_i, _j, BatchSizeIndex, col_num, _Indices))  
            return tf.add(_i,1), BatchSizeIndex, r_loop2[3], r_loop2[4]

        _Indices = tf.zeros((1200,3), dtype=tf.int32)
        col_num = tf.constant(0)
        _i = tf.constant(0)
        condition_loop1 = lambda _i, BatchSizeIndex, col_num, _Indices: tf.less(_i, 200)
        r_loop1 = tf.while_loop(condition_loop1, loop1, loop_vars=(_i, BatchSizeIndex, col_num, _Indices))
        return r_loop1[-1]
    
    def call(self, images, training):
        batch_size = tf.shape(images)[0]
        new_data = tf.zeros((batch_size, 200, 6), dtype=tf.float64)
        images = tf.cast(images, dtype=tf.float64)
        if training:
            data = self.execute(images, batch_size, new_data, tf.constant(True))
        else:
            data = self.execute(images, batch_size, new_data, tf.constant(False))
        
        return data
```

The final code can be modified to execute like this.

```
def augmentation(data):
    .....
    return data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    trainDS = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((np.random.rand(3000,2000,6),
                                                  np.concatenate((np.zeros((1500)),np.ones((1500))))))
    trainDS = (
        trainDS
        .cache()
        .shuffle(1000, reshuffle_each_iteration=False)
        .batch(128, drop_remainder=True)
        .prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE))
    
    input = Input((2000,6))
    x = CustomLayer()(input)
    x = LSTM(64, return_sequences=True)(x)
    output = Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')(x)
    model = Model(input, output)
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='BinaryCrossentropy')
    model.fit(trainDS, epochs=3)
```

Results: Alone `tf.data` spend about `18s`, `tf.data`+`CustomLayer` spend about `38s`.

The thing I want to clarify is that the use of `map` in `tf.data` to run augmentation is on the `CPU`, but if I write augmentation in the `Layer`, it should theoretically run on the `GPU`. Why is there such a big gap between the two?

Environment: python3.6, tensorflow2.4.0

Comment: Hello @Linminxiang! Do I understand correctly, that your code is working is expected in terms of functionality, but its execution is too slow when using the augmentation? If I do understand correctly, thats normal behaivor. What you could do is optimize your code for performance. One thing that comes to my mind is in your data pipeline. You should first apply batch() and than map(augmentation). In that way map is not called on each sample but on each batch, which means less executions and also it does take advantege of vectorization.

Comment: @SaschaKirch, You are right, the code works. The thing I want to clarify is that the use of `map` in `tf.data` to run augmentation is on the `CPU`, but if I write augmentation in the `Layer`, it should theoretically run on the `GPU`. Why is there such a big gap between the two? In addition, maybe something like you said, I may need to optimize my code, there are many `if else` and `loop` in my code, I don't know if it will affect the performance.

Comment: Ok now I understand thank you! I would gues that the issue lies in the different strenghts of GPUs and CPUs. GPUs are good to accelerate computations that can be parallelized such as algebra while CPU are good at general tasks such as indexing, loading etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reduced the `tf.gather` method in the code, and used `tf.TensorArray` instead of the `tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update` method, which really optimized my training speed, from 2min to 2s.